# Creating post request using Volley with Kotlin

Tags: post, kotlin, android-volley

I found following code as example how to create post request with Volley in Java but my whole project is in Kotlin. How would equivalent Kotlin code look like?

```
 {     
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
    {  
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("name", "Alif");  
            params.put("domain", "http://itsalif.info");

            return params;  
    }
};
```

Link to the example code: https://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in the function you took that snippet from:

```
{
        val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap();
        params.put("name", "Alif");
        params.put("domain", "http://itsalif.info");

        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            return params;
        }
}
```